# Django - how to exclude repeating objects

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Локация", default=u'')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Страна", default=u'')

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u"Страна")

class Photo(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, verbose_name=u'Фото')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['name', 'country']


    photos = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(LocationForm, self).save(commit)
        for each in self.cleaned_data['photos']:
            Photo.objects.create(photo=each, location=instance)

        return instance
```

views.py

```
class AddLocationPageView(CreateView):
    model = Location
    form_class = LocationForm
    template_name = 'add_location.html'

class BrowseLocationsPageView(ListView):
    model = Country
    context_object_name = 'countries'
    template_name = "browse_locations.html"
```

add_location.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

browse_locations.html

```
{% for country in countries %}
            {{ country }}
{% endfor %}
```

I need to get in browse_locations.html the list of countries without repeating.
For exapmple, I am creating location object with country 'USA'. Then I am creating second one with country 'USA'. And in my view I can see the list where there are two 'USA', but I need only one.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is your end goal here? are you trying to show sub lists by grouping things by countries, or are you trying to get distinct entries in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using postgres, then you can use the [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) queryset filter with a field name.

```
class BrowseLocationsPageView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.distinct('name')
```

---

This solves the "issue" but there is a bigger problem at hand. Wherever you are creating the countries, you are creating new countries instead of looking if there is an existing country with the same name - [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) may be useful here.

<sub><sub>Location should probably have a foreign key to a country too...</sub></sub>

Comment: I knew that problem was in cretaing the same country again but I couldn't find solution and decided to work around this trouble in view (via distinct choice). Please, tell me where should I apply this get_or_create method?.. in save() in forms or in form_valid() in view ? thanks!

Comment: @Dennis - There isn't enough information here to really make much of a decision, You probably want to make the form invalid if you're trying to create a country that already exists, hard to say, either way it is outside the scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

You have country as a CharField in the Location Model. Hence the repitition.

Change the country field as a ForeignKey in the Location model

Comment: I've tried.. in this case I have the error on my field in the form (in view) that there is no such choice